What formula could be making this number-triangle?
The coefficients of a polynomial in $\lambda$ in the Taylor expansion around $r=0$ of the integral
$$ \int_{1-r}^{1+r} \frac{1+z^2-r^2}{z\sqrt{4 z^2 r^2 - (-1 + z^2 +r^2)^2}} \exp(-z/\lambda)\;dz $$
for successive $n$ are
1 1
1 2  3   3
1 3  9  24   45    45
1 4 18  78  285   810  1575   1575
1 5 30 180  975  4545 17325  50400   99225   99225
1 6 45 345 2475 16020 90720 434700 1686825 4961250 9823275 9823275
...

What could be making this pattern?
I know that the last terms in each row are (2n-1)!! (2n+1)!! . (See https://oeis.org/A079484 .)
The third column (starting with n=2 in the second row) is 3(-1 + n)(n)/2, this is like the Triangular Matchstick numbers, https://oeis.org/A045943.
The fourth column is (-1 + n)(n)(-7 + 5n)/2; this is like (offset by one index) the Heptagonal pyramidal numbers, https://oeis.org/A002413.
The fifth column (45,285,...) is like $(5/8)(-2 + n)(-1 + n)(n)(-9 + 7n)$, starting with n=3.
This seems promising but then the fifth column is $3/8 (-2 + n) (-1 + n) (n)(62 - 77 n + 21 n^2)$...
Mathematica code to generate these polynomials (see the numerator of the pattern, and divide by $e^{-1/\lambda}\pi$) is:
$Assumptions = {0 <= r <= 1, \[Lambda] > 0}

Series[(1/(Exp[-1/\[Lambda]]\[Pi]))Integrate[ (1 + z^2 - r^2)/(
   z Sqrt[4 z^2 r^2 - (-1 + z^2 + r^2)^2])
    Exp[-z/\[Lambda]], {z, 1 - r, 1 + r}], {r, 0, 2n}]

For $n=3$ this becomes
$$
\begin{align}
 & = 1 \\
 & +\frac{1 + \lambda}{4}\left(\frac{r}{\lambda}\right)^2 \\
 & +\frac{1 + 2 \lambda + 3 \lambda^2 + 3 \lambda^3}{64}\left(\frac{r}{\lambda}\right)^4 \\
 & +\frac{1 + 3 \lambda + 9 \lambda^2 + 24 \lambda^3 + 45 \lambda^4 + 45 \lambda^5}{2304}\left(\frac{r}{\lambda}\right)^6 . \\
\end{align}
$$
I'm wondering about the polynomials in the numerators here.
(The quantities in the denominator are $4^n(n!)^2$, where for example 64 is the $n=2$ term.)

I have trouble following this. Can you explicitly define the polynomials you are referring to and provide examples?

I've provided examples now. Does this help?

Yes, I see now what you mean. (But I don't have any insight into these coefficients.)

I've found a much quicker way to generate them via a Taylor series of a related integrand:
$ \frac{1}{n!}\frac{d}{d^n r} \exp(-(\sqrt{1 - r^2 \sin^2 \theta} - r \cos \theta)/\lambda) $.
Setting $r \to 0$ yields terms with powers of $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$. These are easy to integrate (over $\theta = 0$ to $2\pi$) using the formula $\sin^{n} \cos^{m} \to (2\Gamma((m+1)/2)\Gamma((n+1)/2))/(m+n)!$. I haven't examined in detail the recurrent(?) processes when taking repeated derivatives that creates the coefficients.
I do know that the fourth column is three times OEIS A002413.

The values in the triangle are given by
$$T(n,k) = \frac{2^n \frac{n}{2}!}{\pi\,n!} \sum_{c\,=\,\max(k-n/2,\,0)}^{\min(k/2,\,n)} t(n,k,c) $$
where each row is given by an even $n$, and
$$t = \frac{(k-c)_c}{2^c} \binom{-c+k-1}{c} \binom{n}{2 c-2 k+n}\Gamma\left(-c+k+\frac{1}{2}\right)  \Gamma
   \left(c-k+\frac{n+1}{2}\right) (-2 c+2 k-1)\text{!!}    $$
where $(x)_y$ is the Pochhammer symbol, $\binom{x}{y}$ is a binomial, $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function, and !! is the double factorial (n*(n-2)*...). Here Pochhammer is preferred to a ratio of Gamma functions because it is 1 rather than undefined when $x=y=0$.
Update to answer @lhf's question about how this was found.

It turns out the integral I had in the Question wasn't the right form to analyze. The original integral was

$$ I = \int_0^{2\pi} f d\theta$$
where $$f = \exp(-\left(\sqrt{1-r \sin^2 \theta)} - r \cos\theta\right)/\lambda).$$
(This can be transformed into the form seen in the Question above, more or less by setting $z= \left(\sqrt{1-r \sin^2 \theta)} - r \cos\theta\right)$.)

For this problem $0 \le r \le 1$. As in the Question above, I expanded the integrand in a Taylor series around $r=0$. This is considerably easier to differentiate, since $r$ appears only in the integrand, rather than also in the integration limits.
With the integrand expressed as a Taylor series $I$ is

$$ I = \int_0^{2 \pi} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{r^n}{n!} \left(\left. \frac{d}{dr^n} f\right) \right|_{r=0}  \; d\theta.$$
Since the integral is over $\theta$ only we can move the integral sign inside the sum:
$$ I =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{r^n}{n!} \int_0^{2 \pi} \left(\left. \frac{d}{dr^n} f\right) \right|_{r=0}  \; d\theta.$$
The task is then to find a general form for the coefficient
$$a_n = \int_0^{2 \pi} \left(\left. \frac{d}{dr^n} f\right) \right|_{r=0}  \; d\theta.$$

When you take (successive) derivatives of $f$ you get sums of terms of the form

$$ \left(\frac{r^p \sin^{2s}\theta\, \cos^q \theta}{\lambda^g \left(1 - r^2 \sin^2 \theta\right)^m}\right)f.$$
where $p, s, q$ and $g$ are non-negative integers, and $m$ can be an integer or half-integer ($0, 1/2, 1, 3/2$ etc ...).
Let's consider taking the derivative of a general one of these terms.
The existing $\sin^{2s}\cos^q / \lambda^g$ are independent of $r$. What remains (eliding the $\theta$ for brevity) is
$$ \frac{1}{f}\frac{d}{dr} \frac{r^p}{\left(1 - r^2 \sin^2 \right)^m} f =
\frac{r^{p+1}\,sin^2}{\lambda (1 - r^2 \sin^2)^{m+1/2}} 
+ \frac{r^p \cos}{\lambda (1 - r^2 \sin^2)^{m}} 
+ \frac{2 m\,r^{p+1}\sin^2}{(1 - r^2 \sin^2)^{m+1}}
+ \frac{p\,r^{p-1}}{(1 - r^2 \sin^2)^{m}}.
$$
Thinking of the combination of $\{p, s, q, m, g\}$ as a point in a 5-d space, the derivative operation yields up to four new points with associated weights $1$, $1$, $2m$, and $p$:
    {p+1, m+1/2, s+1, q  , g+1}   # A
+   {p  , m    , s  , q+1, g+1}   # B
+ 2m{p+1, m+1  , s+1, q  , g }    # C
+  p{p-1, m    , s  , q  , g }    # D

I say up to four new points because if $m=0$ (as in the base $f$) or if $p=0$ (also in the base $f$, and along paths where $p$ increased and then decreased to zero) then those terms will not be generated. I've labeled the four new points, or steps, as $A, B, C, D$.
Looking back up to our goal: we will find $a_n$ by taking $n$ steps along all the possible paths, or, the valid combinations of $A,B,C,D$ of length $n$), then setting $r$ to zero, and finally integrating over $\theta$ to end up with a polynomial in terms of $1/\lambda$.
The coefficient of each power of $\lambda$ is formed from the sum of the weights of all the valid paths that generate $\lambda$'s of that power.

Now let's start to analyze this situation.

a. The fact that we set $r$ to zero before integrating means that the only terms left to integrate will be ones with the power $p=0$.
Steps $A$ and $C$ both raise $p$, and step $D$ decreases it.
So, a term will remain only if the sum of the number of $A$s and $C$s equals the number of $D$s along a path: $a + c - d = 0$.
The order of the $A$, $C$s, and $Ds$ contributes an extra weight to path because of the coefficient $p$ when step $D$ is taken. For example, $AAADDD$ has a weight of $3 * 2 * 1 = 6$ but $ADADAD$ has a weight of $1*1*1=1$. $A$ and $C$ are equivalent here.
As mentioned before, not all paths are valid: all the prefix substrings must have the number of (A's or C's) greater than or equal to the number of D's, or else the weight will crash down to zero (basically from differentiating a constant).
For paths of length 4
AADD : weight of 2
ADAD : weight of 1
ADDA : invalid
DAAD : invalid
DADA : invalid
DDAA : invalid

I found experimentally that the sum of the weights of all these paths is $$(2(a+c)-1)!! $$ where $!!$ is the double factorial.
b. In the above process, the order of $A$s and $C$s does not matter.
But, there is also a weight for each path which is from the coefficients $2m$, which depends only on the order of the $A$s and $C$s. Each $A$ increases $m$ by $1/2$ and each $C$ multiplies the weight by $2m$ and increments $m$ by $1$.
I simulated this process and found that the pattern of the sum of the weights over all permutations of $A$ and $C$ here was basically the same as the Bessel numbers, but with the indices shifted. This yielded a factor of $$\frac{(a + 2c - 1)!}{2^c (a-1)!c!}.$$
c. The steps $B$ can be inserted anywhere in the above sequences without changing the outcome of the $n$-weights or $m$-weights.
This contributes a factor $$\binom{2(a+c) + b}{b}.$$
d. I noticed experimentally that the $n=\text{odd}$ derivatives are always zero, because they have only $q=\text{odd}$ powers of cosine.
But the $n$-even derivatives also have only even powers of cosine.
This is because if $n = a + b + c + d$ is even, and $(a+c) = d$ then $a + c + d$ is even, so $b$ (which contributes a power of cosine) is even.
Therefore before integrating over $\theta$, $a_n$ is a sum of terms $\cos^n, \cos^{n-2}\sin^{2}, \cos^{n-4}\sin^4, \ldots \sin^{n}$.
e. $A$ and $C$ both bring a factor of $\sin^2$, while $A$ and $B$ bring a factor of $1/\lambda$. Also $a + c = d$. For any given $\lambda^{k-n}$ and combination of $\cos$ and $\sin$ there is a limited range of $c$ which end up contributing. This leads to the restrictions on the sum to form the term with power $\lambda^{k-n}$, where $c$ ranges from $\max(k - n/2, 0)$ to $\min(k/2, n)$.
f. Finally, integrate. The integral of $\sin^{2s}\theta\cos^q\theta$ contributes a factor $$\frac{2 \Gamma \left(\frac{q+1}{2}\right) \Gamma
   \left(s+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{q}{2}+s+1\right)}$$
(and remember that the useful $q$ here are always even).
The final $T(n,k)$ comes from multiplying all these factors. Some minor cleanup leads to expressing the Bessel-like numbers (from part b) as the Pochhammer symbol.

How did you find this formula?

Bravo, I am extremely impressed with the depth of this answer! I would like to know how you reached the conclusion of the general form of successive derivatives shown in Step 3. Probably trivial to you, but I am interested to see the process.

Thank you! Nothing's trivial here. For step 3, I first noticed it experimentally. I use Mathematica, so just differentiating $f$ and using Simplify and Expand. Mathematica can also automatically differentiate the general form (the thing in the first equation in Step 3), which is what I did, but you can verify it by hand as well. Basically, there are (up to) four successor terms because there's one r with the sin^2 term in the exponent $f$ (A),
one r with the cos term in the exponent $f$ (B),
one r in the denominator (C),
and one r in the numerator (D).
